# Audio is scrambled up when using ffmpeg concat demuxer

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, codec, aac

I am using ffmpeg's concat demuxer to join different mp4 videos. First I have reencoded all videos with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i "${file}" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "${out}"
```

To concatenate the videos, I follow [the ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol). My command for concatenating 3 videos looks like this:

```
mkfifo temp1 temp2 temp3

ffmpeg -y -i "${file1}" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp1 2>/dev/null & \
ffmpeg -y -i "${file2}" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp2 2>/dev/null & \
ffmpeg -y -i "${file3}" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp3 2>/dev/null & \

ffmpeg -y -f mpegts -i "concat:temp1|temp2|temp3|" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "${out}"
```

The video of the output file works like a charm. But the audio is scrambled up, and when playing it e.g. in mpv, I get many errors such as these:

> [ffmpeg/audio] aac: Input buffer exhausted before END element found
> Error decoding audio. [ffmpeg/audio] aac: Number of scalefactor bands
> in group (15) exceeds limit (14). Error decoding audio. [ffmpeg/audio]
> aac: TYPE_FIL: Input buffer exhausted before END element found Error
> decoding audio.

How can I make the audio work when concatenating several mp4 videos?

Comment: You're using the concat protocol instead of the concat demuxer. For proper concatenation all of the inputs must have the same attributes. Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4`

Comment: Your inputs may not have the same channel count or sampling rate. During re-encode, add `-ac 2` to force 2 channels and `-ar 48000` to force 48 KHz.

Comment: @llogan @Gyan: Thanks to both of you. I am using now the demuxer and `-ac 2 -ar 48000` and it works like a charm!